# Is it possible to update the mosaico versafix template to the 1.1.16 version?

Tags: mosaico

Mosaico has an updated version of the versafix template -

[Mosaico Versafix 1.1.16](https://mosaico.io/news/update-to-our-versafix-master-template-for-emails/)

What is required to add/replace the current versafix with this updated version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check out the version from github repo and place the template in your installation. I have just cloned https://github.com/voidlabs/versafix-template/tree/v1.1.19/dist/template folder to my Mosaico templates folder and it works.

You can copy the folder as versafix-new and rename html file as template-versafix-new.html so your legacy copy wouldn't get overrided.

p.s. The blog post was about 1.5 years old so my answer is about 1.1.19 instead of 1.1.16.

Comment: Thanks, 1.19 works great once installed.